# Desktop stops working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop, windows-explorer

I'm having an odd problem on one of my Windows 7 machines.  At machine startup, explorer.exe is working properly - I can use the Start menu, click on desktop icons, etc.   At some later point, though, I lose the ability to interact with desktop icons.  I can't double-click to open files on the desktop, and I can't right-click to see the properties window.

Oddly enough the Start menu still works properly, and I can still open an Explorer window into my desktop and access everything.  I can get around the problem by killing explorer.exe and restarting it using Task Manager, but it's annoying to have to do this over and over.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I took a look at startup files with msconfig and didn't see any obvious problems.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done a virus scan?

Comment: Virus scan turns up nothing - I'm running Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: It sounds like a bad shell-extension. Have you installed any “desktop-enhancement” software?

Comment: I second @Synetech there, use something like [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to find out

Answer (score 1):

Look in your event log for errors around the time of the explorer.exe failure.

Also are you running a particular piece of software when the error happens?

Comment: This is really frustrating, but after happening every day for weeks, it hasn't happened again since I posted the question.   I'll check these things the next time explorer freezes.

Comment: OK, it happened again.  No errors in the System log. The only error in the Application log is this one:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\ia64\msvsmon.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="ia64",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
I'm not sure why the .NET remote debugger was called, or if it could have any bearing on my problem.

Comment: I think it loads on startup

Comment: I believe but am not positive that developed applications might call the debugger. So it could be something else causing the debugger to crash.